# What is the difference between infura and geth?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I understand both methods are used for running dapps. What I don't understand is the clear cut difference between the two or how one is more advantageous over the other? I'm new to blockchain, so please explain with a simple terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is:

- Infura has `geth` installation running for you, exposing most used, most low-CPU-consuming methods for you via Web.
- You can install `geth` yourself but you will need a server with about 500GB of SSD disk, and wait 1 month to download the entire State.

If you are not going to do any serious monetary transfers I recommend using Etherscan, it is more complete than Infura.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by using etherscan as an alternative. Isn't etherscan simply blockchain where all trasactions are recorded?

Comment: "wait 1 month to download" - this is more like few days

Comment: EtherScan is not an alternative to a full node, as EtherScan provides proprietary API that has different methods than Ethereum nodes.

Comment: As a free alternative you can use Cloudflare hosted nodes: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ethereum-gateway/

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa most cloud computing platforms have SSD storage remotely connected, so it isn't microsencond latency, it is like millisecond latency.

Answer (score 1):

To execute transactions and/or queries against blockchains, you need connections.

1. Infura is an API gateway to main network and some test networks. It supports a subset of web3 interface. When you like to execute a transaction against the Ethereum blockchain, you may use infura as connection to the blockchain. So in this case, you are not directly connected to Ethereum, but infura has a connection. The Metamask Browser Plugin works with infura.
2. The alternative approach is to have an Ethereum client like geth or parity running on your machine. In this case, the Ethereum Client connects to several public nodes of the blockchain and forwards your transactions to the blockchain.

Depending on your architecture and requirements, both approaches could be the best solution.